Proving the general formula of mountain-like cycle permutations
We can view a permutation of the integers $1$ to $n$ as the pairs
$$(1,a_1), (2, a_2), \cdots (n,a_n)$$
where $a_1, a_2, \cdots , a_n$ are the integers $1$ to $n$.
Define a permutation to be "mountain-like" if the $a_1, a_2, \cdots , a_n$ first increases and then decreases. How can I prove that the number of mountain-like permutations that have only 1 cycle is given by the formula
$$a(n) = \frac{1}{2n} \cdot \left(\sum_{\text{odd} \ d \ \text{divides}\  n} \mu(d)\cdot2^{n/d}\right)$$
I know that I have to use Mobius Inversion to prove that, but seem a little stuck here. Any insights?
